# How to create pivot table based on DataFrame with 2 main columns in index and rest columns in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, aggregation

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

Data type:

- ID - numeric
- U1, U2, U3 - numeric (binary 0/1)
- CP - string (range)
- CH - numeric (binary 0/1)
- MG - string (P / M / BM)

| ID | U1 | U2 | U3 | CP | CH | MG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 10-20 | 1 | P |
| 222 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 10-20 | 1 | P |
| 333 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 20-30 | 0 | BM |
| 444 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 40-50 | 0 | BM |
| 555 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 10-20 | 0 | M |

And I need to create pivot table, as below (ids is index):

- COUNT_CP - How many ID have defined in index combination U and CP columns
- COUNT_U - How many ID have '1' in each 'U' column
- PERC_CH - Percent of '1' in column 'CH' for each defined in index combination U and CP
- COUNT_MG_P - How many ID has 'P' in column 'MG' for each defined in index combination U and CP
- COUNT_MG_M - How many ID has 'P' in column 'MG' for each defined in index combination U and CP
- COUNT_MG_BM - How many ID has 'P' in column 'MG' for each defined in index combination U and CP

  ```
     idx |  idx     | COUNT_CP | COUNT_U  | PERC_CH | COUNT_MG_P | COUNT_MG_M | COUNT_MG_BM |
    -----|----------|----------|----------|---------|------------|------------|-------------|
      U1 | CP_10_20 | 3        | 3        | 0.66    | 2          | 1          | 0           |
  -------|----------|----------|----------|---------|------------|------------|-------------|
         | CP_20_30 | 0        | 3        | 0       | 0          | 0          | 0           |   
  -------|----------|----------|----------|---------|------------|------------|-------------|            
         | CP_30_40 | 0        | 3        | 0       | 0          | 0          | 0           |   
   ------|----------|----------|----------|---------|------------|------------|-------------|          
         | CP_40_50 | 0        | 3        | 0       | 0          | 0          | 0           | 
  -------|----------|----------|----------|---------|------------|------------|-------------|            
      U2 | CP_10_20 | 2        | 3        | 1.00    | 1          | 0          | 0           |  
  -------|----------|----------|----------|---------|------------|------------|-------------|        
         | CP_20_30 | 0        | 3        | 0       | 0          | 0          | 1           |   
  -------|----------|----------|----------|---------|------------|------------|-------------|        
         | CP_30_40 | 0        | 3        | 0       | 0          | 0          | 1           | 
  -------|----------|----------|----------|---------|------------|------------|-------------|            
         | CP_40_50 | 1        | 3        | 0       | 0          | 0          | 0           |  
  -------|----------|----------|----------|---------|------------|------------|-------------|           
      U3 | CP_10_20 | 1        | 2        | 1.00    | 1          | 0          | 0           | 
  -------|----------|----------|----------|---------|------------|------------|-------------|            
         | CP_20_30 | 0        | 2        | 0       | 0          | 0          | 0           |  
  -------|----------|----------|----------|---------|------------|------------|-------------|           
         | CP_30_40 | 0        | 2        | 0       | 0          | 0          | 0           | 
  -------|----------|----------|----------|---------|------------|------------|-------------|             
         | CP_40_50 | 1        | 2        | 0       | 0          | 0          | 1           |
  ```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframe you provided (which does not seem to be the one you used to illustrate the expected result, since it does not have `30_40` value in `CP` column, for instance):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [111, 222, 333, 444, 555],
        "U1": [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        "U2": [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        "U3": [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        "CP": ["10-20", "10-20", "20-30", "40-50", "10-20"],
        "CH": [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        "MG": ["P", "P", "BM", "BM", "M"],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
dfs = []
for item in ["U1", "U2", "U3"]:
    # Slice initial dataframe
    df_temp = df.assign(idx1=item, idx2="CP_" + df["CP"].str.replace("-", "_"))
    df_temp = df_temp.groupby(["idx1", "idx2"]).agg(list)

    # Add new columns
    df_temp["COUNT_CP"] = df_temp[item].apply(sum)
    df_temp["COUNT_U"] = (
        df_temp["U1"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x else 0)
        + df_temp["U2"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x else 0)
        + df_temp["U3"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x else 0)
    )
    df_temp["PERC_CH"] = df_temp["CH"].apply(lambda x: round(sum(x) / len(x), 2))
    df_temp["COUNT_MG_P"] = df_temp["MG"].apply(
        lambda x: len([v for v in x if v == "P"])
    )
    df_temp["COUNT_MG_M"] = df_temp["MG"].apply(
        lambda x: len([v for v in x if v == "M"])
    )
    for suffix in ["P", "M", "BM"]:
        df_temp[f"COUNT_MG_{suffix}"] = df_temp.apply(
            lambda x: len([v for v in x["MG"] if v == suffix and x["COUNT_CP"] != 0]),
            axis=1,
        )

    # Cleanup
    df_temp = df_temp.drop(columns=["ID", "U1", "U2", "U3", "CP", "CH", "MG"])

    dfs.append(df_temp)

new_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

```py
print(new_df)
# Output
               COUNT_CP  COUNT_U  PERC_CH  COUNT_MG_P  COUNT_MG_M  COUNT_MG_BM
idx1 idx2
U1   CP_10_20         3        3     0.67           2           1            0
     CP_20_30         0        3     0.00           0           0            0
     CP_40_50         0        3     0.00           0           0            0
U2   CP_10_20         1        3     0.67           2           1            0
     CP_20_30         1        3     0.00           0           0            1
     CP_40_50         1        3     0.00           0           0            1
U3   CP_10_20         1        3     0.67           2           1            0
     CP_20_30         0        3     0.00           0           0            0
     CP_40_50         1        3     0.00           0           0            1
```